# Getting the index of a list from a string in another list

Tags: c#, list, indexing

I have two lists:

```
public static List<Dinosaur> Dinosaurs = new List<Dinosaur>();
public static List<DinosaurSpecies> DinosaurSpeciesList = new List<DinosaurSpecies>();
```

I want to use the Species in the first list to find the key of the Species in the second list. The following throws a 'has some invalid arguments' but it does illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
int index = MainWindow.DinosaurSpeciesList.FindIndex(MainWindow.Dinosaurs[i].Specie);
```

In other words, where does the Species in the Dinosaurs list [index] appear in the list of all `DinosaurSpecies`?

Comment: Why didn't you use a Map or Dictionary like data structure ?

Comment: Also that likely won't compile unless `.Specie` is a `Predicate<T>`.

Comment: Well, these list structures are used all over the program and are working out pretty good so far. I'm sure there's a simple solution; probably just my syntax.

Comment: .Specie if a field (predicate? never heard that word used that way here before) in the Dinosaur class.

Comment: Also, the singular of “species” is “species”.

Comment: @zetar [`Predicate<T>` is simply a type of delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx).

Comment: @minitech: That is correct, but often in programming we need to clearly differentiate between lists and single objects. In instances like this, it is common (at least in my experience) to add/remove an `S`, even if we need to make up words to do so. Alternatively though, we could use `SpeciesItem` and `SpeciesItems`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by passing a [predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx) to the `FindIndex` method:

```
int index = MainWindow.DinosaurSpeciesList.FindIndex(x => x.Specie == MainWindow.Dinosaurs[i].Specie);
```

Basically, you are saying: Find the index of the element whos `Specie` property is equal to the specified `Dinosaur.Specie` property

---

A simplified and more understandable example might be:

```
Dinosaur dinosaur = GetDinosaurToFindSpeciesInformationFor();
int index = DinosaurSpeciesList.FindIndex(x => x.Specie == dinosaur.Specie);
```

Of course, if you then plan to only use the index to get the DinosaurSpecies object anyway, you could do this:

```
DinosaurSpecies species = DinosaurSpeciesList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Specie == dinosaur.Specie);
//NOTE: species will be null if there are no matches, or more than one match
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Also, I'm 'guaranteed' to never have a null or more than one match because when an 'individual' dinosaur is created it gets its 'species' from the DinosaurSpeciesList. Now, I want to use this as an index to pull other data from the DinosaurSpeciesList (like how much food it needs to eat every day/KG).

Comment: @zetar: Just checked out your blog, I think it's a fantastic idea and wish the best of luck to you and your team during the development. I will look forward to seeing the finished product!

Comment: `FindIndex` is not a LINQ method; the only LINQ method used in this answer is `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: @Servy. Correct. You have passed the test.

Comment: @musefan You should correct your first statement accordingly.

Comment: @Servy: Out of interest, and other than commenting out `using System.Linq`, how can we easily identify a LINQ method?

Comment: @musefan A method defined in the `system.LINQ` namespace is a LINQ method, the rest aren't.  You can use MSDN, visual studio, etc. to determine where a particular function is defined, and whether or not it's one of the functions in that namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Your parameters to `FindIndex` are wrong.  The single-parameter form requires a lambda (or more specifically, a `Predicate<T>`):

```
int index = MainWindow.DinosaurSpeciesList.FindIndex(x => x.Specie.Equals(MainWindow.Dinosaurs[i].Specie));
```

Depending on what your `DinosaurSpecies` class looks like, of course.

*ps. I like dinosaurs*